# Applescript to launch XAMPP osx, won't enter password on pop-up?

Tags: macos, xampp, applescript

**Hello All,
First of, thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm having an issue with my applescript i wrote to launch XAMPP on OSX (10.10.1).
Lauching the app goes fine, but i want the script to enter my password (there is a popup at launch,asking for the root password). Here's what i tried:**

do shell script "sudo open /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/manager-osx.app" password "MyPassword" with administrator privileges

tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell

tell application frontApp
    set window_name to name of front window
end tell

tell application "Application Manager"
    keystroke "MyPassword"
end tell

**But it won't work. Any clue what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with a workaround, i now run a shell script to

"open /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start" with administrator priviliges

then, there is no pop-up